# How can I set resultsCount to 0 if obj_list.length only returns 1 in my JavaScript counter?

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to create a counter that loops thru a set of results and gives the total counts as resultscount. I'm fairly new to JS so the issue i'm having is if the count only returns 1 i want to set the Countsresult to 0. I know the counting section at the top works as i've tested it but dont know the syntax to make Resultcount = 0 if obj_list.length only returns 1. Any help would greatly be appreciated

```
return obj_list.map(x =\> {
var obj = Object.assign({}, x);
obj\['resultsCount'\] = obj_list.length;
return obj;





if obj_list.length = 1
 then obj['resultsCount'] = 0;` `
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your aim, but it seems, that you want something like this

```
obj_list.length === 1 ? obj['result_count'] = 0 : obj['result_count'] = 1
```